# git diff suppress "no newline at end of file"

Tags: git, git-diff

How can I suppress the "no newline at end of file" warning in git diff?

```
$ printf "1">1
$ printf "2">2
$ git diff 1 2
diff --git a/1 b/2
index 56a6051..d8263ee 100644
--- a/1
+++ b/2
@@ -1 +1 @@
-1
\ No newline at end of file
+2
\ No newline at end of file
```

Comment: Looks like this is annoying to turn off. [Maybe related](https://superuser.com/a/457341/259670)

Comment: Don't know how you can isolate that specific warning, but `--ignore-space-at-eol` is probably the closest.

Answer (score 0):

it's not perfect as it might erroneously remove the literal string from the diff if present, but ignoring that edge-case, you can use grep's

```
-v, --invert-match
       Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

to filter it out:

```
git diff 1 2 --color | grep -vF '\ No newline at end of file'
```

works fine:

[image]

Comment: With `^` it shouldn't match on literal strings in the diff since the diff uses `-`, `+`, or space (context lines) at the start of every line.

Comment: Agreed with regards to `^`.  Would have to drop `-F` in that case to enable regex. Also  backslash should then be escaped as double-backslash